# Background Image not rendering in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I need to have a background image on my website. I tried using the `img` tag and this one does work but because I am trying to use Tailwind to have my image styled I would much prefer using the `background` tag.

This is my current component's code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import houseImg from '../imgs/house-backg-orig.jpg'
import HomePageDescr from '../components/HomePageDescr'

function Home() {

  return (
      
    <div className="">
      <Header/>
      <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url('${houseImg}')` }} />
      <HomePageDescr/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

Everything renders but the actual background. I tried looking at various things here but no questions/answers helped. Not adding `require` to the image, nothing.

Anyone encountered the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: `url('${houseImg}')` `url(${houseImg})` try this

Comment: Tried - doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to resize the `div`. Try setting `height` and `width` for the div